# flume not fetching Facebook data using SocialAgent

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, flume, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to retrieve facebook data using flume SocialAgent. I have successfully retrieve twitter data using TwitterAgent.

But in case of Facebook I got nothing in hdfs.

[image]

My terminal stuck at this stage. When I terminate this process I got this

[image]

And my HDFS facebook folder is empty.I am using following flume.conf

```
SocialAgent.sources = FacebookHttpSource Twitter
SocialAgent.channels = FBmemoryChannel MemChannel
SocialAgent.sinks = fbHDFS HDFS

# For each one of the sources, the type is defined
SocialAgent.sources.FacebookHttpSource.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
SocialAgent.sources.FacebookHttpSource.port = 51400
SocialAgent.sources.FacebookHttpSource.interceptors = Ts
SocialAgent.sources.FacebookHttpSource.interceptors.Ts.type = org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampInterceptor$Builder

# The channel can be defined as follows.
SocialAgent.sources.FacebookHttpSource.channels = FBmemoryChannel

# Each sink's type must be defined
#Specify the channel the sink should use
SocialAgent.sinks.fbHDFS.channel = FBmemoryChannel
SocialAgent.sinks.fbHDFS.type = hdfs
SocialAgent.sinks.fbHDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/flume/facebook/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
SocialAgent.sinks.fbHDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
SocialAgent.sinks.fbHDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
SocialAgent.sinks.fbHDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
SocialAgent.sinks.fbHDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
SocialAgent.sinks.fbHDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

# Each channel's type is defined.
SocialAgent.channels.FBmemoryChannel.type = memory

# Other config values specific to each type of channel(sink or source)
# can be defined as well
# In this case, it specifies the capacity of the memory channel
SocialAgent.channels.FBmemoryChannel.capacity = 10000
SocialAgent.channels.FBmemoryChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

**Is there any other flume Agent to fetch FaceBook Data.**

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you on this question after a long time, I hope you got success in this task if so could you please share how to do all the process i.e. extracting the data from Facebook, I mean all the steps please. I do have idea about process of extracting data from twitter. please help to achieve this task. If it is not possible to mention to all steps/process here please email me on nalamdinesh@gmail.com. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource* in your configuration doesn't send any request to Facebook to fetch data. It just listening a port (in your case 51400) and wait for any request 
(https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#http-source)

As I know there isn't any Flume FBClient yet.